# Error importing data

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009

I want to migrate table-data from one AX to another.

**Simple example**:

I have created a table `test`, having two columns `id` and `value`.
I also created a definition group in *Administration* / *Periodic* / *Data import, export* / *Definition groups* and via *table-setup* I selected my table `test`. Table fields `id` and `value` are also selected and set active in *Field setup*.

Export is set to *Comma* and works nearly as intended ( There are more fields in export than chosen in *Field setup* ).

File can be viewed by any kind of editor and data looks good.

But trying to import this data does not succeed. There is no error-message at all, just an info-log telling me ( translated from german ):

**Smallest RecId not valid. 0 datasets imported.**

What's the right way to get this import/export-thing working? Export as XLS behaves the same. Export done. Import not possible...

Comment: Are you using the RecID column as part of your exported data?

Comment: I've done the export with and without recid - error stayed the same!

Comment: RecID was part of the import/export definition group?  And you checked the exported data to make sure there were no blank rows?  (blank rows always seem to mess-up my imports)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I hate posts with the exact same question I have but no answer ;)

I had this issue today and solved it by checking 'Include system and shared tables'. This because my table had 'SaveDataPerCompany' set to NO
[image: AX Import options]

If you open the .def(inition) file (export always has a .def and a .dat file) you'll notice that the definition file for a 'normal' table (not shared) has a MIN and a MAX set:
"RECORDIDMIN",5637145841
"RECORDIDMAX",5637156902

Whereas a definition file for a (or at least for my) shared table has the min set to the max value for a variable declared as a long integer ( long , long long int , or bigint)

"RECORDIDMIN",9223372036854775807
"RECORDIDMAX",0

Michael van den Dool